# Android notification application crash when close

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I have an android application where I set a notification using pending intent. I have no problems setting the alarm. However, if quit the application a null pointer exception occurs. Any help? Thanks

Alarm service

```
       int id = intent.getIntExtra("sidAlarm",0);
       Log.w("id",Integer.toString(id));   
       super.onStart(intent, startId);

       mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class);

       Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());

       intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

       PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),id, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
       notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

       mManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Create pending intent

```
                  //Create intent for delete
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(SessionDetails.this, MyReceiver.class);
                  myIntent.putExtra("sidAlarm", pendingIntentId);
                  pendingIntentToDelete = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SessionDetails.this, pendingIntentId, myIntent,0);

                  alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                  alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntentToDelete);
```

Logcat trace

```
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   service com.example.MyAlarmService@4291ff68 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2850)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:159)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at  com.example.MyAlarmService.onStart(MyAlarmService.java:39)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2833)
01-15 18:41:40.584: E/AndroidRuntime(8072):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: added logcat trace. Thanks

Comment: Check line 39 of `MyAlarmService.java`.